# How to install two ionic app into one android system

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

I am new in ionic . I developed two different app using ionic . but I can't install both of them on same android operation system . I know android detect apps according their package name . I using latest version of ionic (5) and capacitor , and not cordova . I changed name and package name in ionic android studio project (in app/res/values/strings.xml and app/res/xml/config.xml) . But still first app replace with the second . could you please give a suggestion . thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In capacitor apps the config.xml is not used for configuring the app, that’s a cordova thing.

What you need to change is the `applicationId` in `android/app/build.gradle` file